# Does homebrew formula has uninstall hook?

Tags: homebrew

My formula need to persist configuration file between upgrade, so I symlink those configuration directory to `/usr/local/var/foo-app`.

I would like to know, does homebrew formula has hook to do clean up when user uninstall the formula. Or Its okay to left `/usr/local/var/foo-app` there.